# Tree from tree paths

Tags: java, jface, treeviewer

In my project I have a lot of data, that can be structured in some way. 
To simplify, let's pretend that that data is a bunch of file paths:

```
/user/homefolder/Folder1/file1.jpg
/user/homefolder/Folder1/file2.jpg
/user/homefolder/Folder2/file3.jpg
/user/homefolder/Folder2/file4.jpg
/user/homefolder/Folder3/file5.jpg
```

So, I have actually tree-paths and I do can group these paths by first three folders or more if there are.

I have this values in a array of arrays. And I don't want to create a duplicate tree-model.

I use JFace `TreeViewer` in `SWT.VIRTUAL` style and the `ILazyTreeContentProvider` doesn't seem to be made to work with this kind of data.

How should I do to be able to create proper tree?

Comment: You might be able to use `ILazyTreePathContentProvider`

Comment: greg-449 I tried but it's methods are totaly the same as ILazyTreeContentProvider has and wrapping all data paths in TreePath is the only difference. Also I didn't find proper tutorial or something. Javadoc of ILTPCP is the same as ILTCP has even datatypes are not chenged.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

https://github.com/johandb/JTree

You can implement your own node

Example

```
Tree<String> root = new Tree<String>();
Tree<String> folder1 = root.add("Folder1");
folder1.add("file1.jpg");
folder1.add("file2.jpg");
Tree<String> folder2 = root.add("Folder2");
folder2.add("file3.jpg");
folder2.add("file4.jpg");
```

etc etc

Regards

Johan